# Arranging a packet of skittles with repetitions of flavor

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A mini bag of skittles contains exactly 6 skittles. 3 red, 1 orange, 0 yellow, 0 green and 2 purple skittles. How many different ways are there to arrange the 6 skittles?

In order to solve this problem I was thinking of two different approaches however both give me different answers so I would like to know which is wrong and why. Thank you!

First approach: stars and bars

There would be 6 stars and 4 bars meaning I can arrange the skittles in 10C6 ways which evaluates to 210. Although the skittles are different colors the one's that are the same color are NOT distinct so this method would allow me to have an unordered set for the package of skittles.

Second approach: treat this as a permutation where I divide by any doubles. If the skittles were all unique they could be arranged in 6! ways however since some colors are repeated the total arrangements would be 6!/2!3!

Which approach is correct and why wouldn't these two approaches evaluate to the same answer?

Comment: What's the point of including the colors with no representatives?

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is correct because

$\quad (1)$: Any two skittles of the same color are indistinguishable

$\quad (2)$: In arrangements, ordering matters.

When one uses binomial numbers $($like $n$ choose $k$), ordering does not matter. Choosing a banana and an apple is the same as choosing an apple and a banana.

Comment: We could solve the problem by choosing $3$ of the six positions for the red skittles, $1$ of the remaining three positions for the orange skittle, and then fill both of the remaining two positions for the purple skittles.  Notice that $$\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2} = \frac{6!}{3!3!} \cdot \frac{3!}{1!2!} \cdot \frac{2!}{2!0!} = \frac{6!}{3!1!2!}$$

Comment: Yes you could, but I don't really see how that relates. Choosing positions $1$, $3$ and $5$ for the red skittles is the same as choosing positions $3$, $1$ and $5$ for the red skittles (because they are indistinguishable). So ordering still does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

[Multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) $\binom {6}{3,2,1} = \frac{6!}{3!\cdot 2!\cdot 1!} = 60$. This corresponds to your second approach.

I don't really understand how you are attempting to use stars and bars there.

Comment: Can't stars and bars be used whenever you are ordering objects but you have some that are indistinguishable?

Comment: All these tools can be used in a variety of circumstances but I can't see it here.

Comment: Stars and bars are generally used to assign objects to "containers".

Comment: Yes, or say assigning categories.

Comment: oh so lets say I was trying to make 5 different mini packets of 6 skittles, rather than just one packet containing 6

Comment: Difficult to say without a specific description but adding the colours to a categorization might mean that stars-and-bars would be only one step within an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So in total you have $6$ skittles out of which $3$ are red,  one is orange and $2$ are purple.  And we need to arrange these skittles

So why don't you consider this problem as forming a $6$ letter word using $3$ *R's* , $1$ *O* and $2$ *P's*.

So the answer simply goes $$\frac {6!}{3!2!}$$